# .NET assembly binding, can I map an assembly to a version in another assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, app-config, .net-assembly

Good Morning,
Is it possible to map assembly requests to the version within another assembly? For instance our product uses NHibernate 3.2. We are moving to NServiceBus 3.2.2. For DBSubscription storage it uses NHibernate and it's baked in version of NHibernate which is 3.3 in NServiceBus.NHibernate.

How can I map requests for NHibernate 3.2.0.2002 to NServiceBus.NHibernate which is 3.3...

```
<assemblyIdentity name="NHibernate"
                          publicKeyToken="aa95f207798dfdb4"
                          culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="3.2.0.2002"
                         newVersion="3.3.0.4000"/> //I need it to be NServiceBus.NHibernate
```

Thanks for any tips or tricks. Samples and Links are always appreciated.

Thanks All!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your binding redirect you can redirect to a different code base using the [`codeBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/efs781xb) element:

```xml
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="NHibernate" publicKeyToken="aa95f207798dfdb4" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="3.2.0.2002" newVersion="3.3.0.4000"/>
    <codeBase version="3.3.0.4000" href="file:///C:/path/to/assembly.dll" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

The public keys must be the same, however. You can not bind to a different assembly that is signed with a different key.

If the keys are different, then you need to recompile your solution against NServiceBus.NHibernate.