# Does ilmerge Solve .NET DLL Version Dependency Hell?

Tags: .net, dll, dependency-management, ilmerge

I've most commonly heard `ilmerge` being used as a way to merge a bunch of dlls into a single executable file, to aid distribution of desktop applications.

Is it also viable to use it as a way to enforce dependency chains in a class library?

For example, assuming I have three components:

```
* dllA
* dllB
* dllC
```

whose dependency chains are:

```
* dllA -> dllC
* dllA -> dllB
* dllB -> dllC
```

Now if `dllC` is rev'd to a new version `v1` to `v2`, is it possible for `dllA` to be forced to use `dllC_v1` while `dllB` is forced to use `dllC_v2`?

```
* dllA -> dllC_v1 
    (dllC_v1 is ilmerged into dllA)

* dllA -> dllB -> dllC_v2
    (dllC_v2 is ilmerged into dllB)
```

Also, how does versioning configuration work in this scenario? If `dllC` relies on a config section to be defined in `web/app.config`, and it's expectation of config schema/keys differs between `dllC_v1` and `dllC_v2`, what happens then?

Comment: No, dllC simply doesn't exist anymore.  It is as if you created a project that merged all of the source code of the three original projects.

Comment: @HansPassant but what if I use `/internalize`? Can't I internalize `dllC_v1` into `dllA` and `dllC_v2` into `dllB`?

Comment: I found this http://www.meedios.com/EN/forum/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=3221 where it says one way to do this is to just have two dlls named based on their version: `dllC_v1` and `dllC_v2`, and then reference each specifically from `dllA` and `dllB`? The trick with the different names is so that when they are copied to the `/bin` folder they won't clash or overwrite one another (a problem which doesn't exist in the GAC, which supports side by side versions).

Comment: This link: http://leecampbell.blogspot.ca/2011/06/isolating-custom-library-dependencies.html suggests another alternative, which is to add dll references as embedded resources?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335577/transitive-dependency-causing-conflicting-version-of-same-dll?rq=1

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460542/using-different-versions-of-the-same-assembly-in-the-same-folder?lq=1